# Disable "Reply" and "Reply All" in smtp message

Tags: smtp, smtpclient

I'd like to disable "Reply" and "Reply All" buttons for message recipients using SMTP MailMessage (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient).  Please let me know if anyone done this.  Currently MS Exchange engine achieved this using Add-in, but my goal is to send smtp message that will have those options disabled.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is impossible. There's no way to do this with the standard protocols (SMTP or otherwise).